# C# readonly vs Get

Tags: c#, properties

Are there any differences between the readonly modifier and get-only properties?

Example:

```
public class GetOnly
{
    public string MyProp { get; }
}

public class ReadOnly
{
    public readonly string MyProp;
}
```

Bonus: is there a way to make an interface that works with both? (to use with generics)

```
public interface ISomething
{
    public string MyProp { get; }
}

public class GetOnly : ISomething
{
    public string MyProp { get; }
}

public class ReadOnly : ISomething // Cannot implement
{
    public readonly string MyProp;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can implement the interface on ReadOnly class with an explicit implementation

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At first glance the property and the field are functionally equivalent and for the normal use cases of storing data and passing it around there is  not much difference in using them.

But you already seem to have found an important issue: Only properties can be part of an interface.

> is there a way to make an interface that works with both?

No.

In addition, many APIs that rely on reflection (EF, Serialization) specifically look for properties.

Comment: Excellent! I was looking at seeing which one would be lighter in memory and ran into this trying to make things more DRY.

Comment: @robjam if you consider using readonly variables instead of get only properties, you should consider using no methods at all and just have a static void main (get the sarcasm?). A get only property is a private readonly field and a public void that returns the value. Nothing else. - http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsB0BhA9gG31QGNkxcIRMBxVCVAJzGIG4AoUSWRFDTAGUgBHdp2jwkadOzYAHYACN8zGMXwBDECBjYYAbzZsYxmPKUrIyGAA99UVMhYBfNk6A==

Comment: You forgot 2 important points:
1) properties can be part not only of an interface, but also of a base class, and can be overridden in a hierarchical chain  from class to class.
2) Only properties can be use as sources in a WPF binding.

Comment: overriding DOES apply to read-only stuff. I can create a read-only `{ get; }` property in a base class and make it virtual. A child class DO can override it, maybe assigning a different constant value in his own constructor, or even changing the whole logic, creating a private field and doing:
`get { return _privateField; }`
leaving the field non read-only and so changeable inside the class.

What do you mean by "WPF is just another of those API"? It's the prince framework to build desktop-app in Windows, so that's not a difference that you can ignore so easily... o.O'

Comment: There's another minor advantage of using a getter - you can easily put a breakpoint on it if you need to see when it's being requested. Minor, but I've used that when I can't work out how to add a custom breakpoint.

Answer (score 50):

You're fundamentally misunderstanding the meaning of both of those definitions. Only exposing the getter says *nothing* about whether or not a value is read-only.

While in this trivial example:

```
public class GetOnly
{
    public string MyProp { get; }
}
```

We can say that `MyProp` will *never* change its value, we cannot always say that a getter-only property will not have its value changed. An example of this is a situation where we *cannot* see the implementation of `GetOnly`, and only know about the public definition - For example, if you were working with a closed-source third party library.

A clearer example is this:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    string MyProp { get; }
}
```

This interface does not say that `MyProp` is read-only. It says that *you* cannot change the property. It says nothing about the behavior of the property. Even worse, it only says you cannot change the property when explicitly casting as `ISomething`.

It's *entirely* possible to implement the interface like so (even though the interface only exposes the getter):

```
public class GetOnly : ISomething
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

`readonly` is a modifier which explicitly enforces the fact that the *value will not ever change, except in the declaration or constructor* (barring workarounds like [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection)).

However, `readonly` cannot work on properties, as properties are simply syntactic sugar for get/set *methods*. Further, interfaces only define methods, and as such you cannot define fields (and by extension, readonly fields).

So to answer your question: Yes, they are worlds apart, and are only similar on the surface.

Answer (score 2):

In the following part:

```
public class GetOnly
{
    public string MyProp {get; }
}
```

`MyProp` is a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). However, in this part:

```
public class ReadOnly
{
    public readonly string MyProp;
}
```

`MyProp` is a [field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx). These are two different things.

> is there a way to make an interface that works with both?

No. Only properties can be put into interfaces. Fields cannot.

Answer (score 2):

One is a field (`readonly`); the other is a property. Interfaces cannot define fields, only properties, methods, indexers and events.

Both can only be assigned via constructor or field initialization, and cannot be changed thereafter.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I modified my answer (in regards to `private set`) based on your response. Thank you!